# RegEx: How to match "anything but" the value in \1

Tags: regex

I'm looking for 'extra' names in a list of name-value pairs. 
Only the names `"ACTIVITY_nnnnn"` are of interest.
Each name suffix `"_nnnnn"` should be the same, and if it's not, 
this is an error condition that should be detected.

Given:

```
OneTwo=ThreeFour
ACTIVITY_11111=56676566
ACTIVITY_11111=ASDFASDF
ACTIVITY_22222=ASDFwSDF
ABC-123=1121
ACTIVITY_33333=ASDFASsF
ACTIVITY_11111=ASFAFA
DEF-XXY=22222
```

In this case, the first mismatch is in `ACTIVITY_11111` vs. `ACTIVITY_22222`.

This expression finds a match when another 'matching' entry is found:

```
ACTIVITY_(\d*=)(.|\r|\n)*ACTIVITY_\1
```

This is exactly the opposite of what I need...if "Not `\1`" was possible, 
then the expression would match if another entry had a different suffix.

Is there a way to specify something like `^\1` or `[^\1]`? 
The word at `\1` can be anything but the value in the capture group.

Comment: Which regular expression library are you using?

Comment: Are you wanting to check on *consecutive* lines, or that there are *no duplicates* in the file, or selecting *the last* match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i think you are asking for is:

```
ACTIVITY_(\d*=)(.|\r|\n)*ACTIVITY_(?!\1)
```

but (1) i'm not sure groups are allowed in lookaheads and (2) it doesn't do exactly what you want - it will match *each* ACTIVITY_11111 with the ACTIVITY_22222 (so you will get multiple matches, or just one but from the first 11111 rather than the last).

what i think you need is:

```
ACTIVITY_(\d*=).*[\r\n]((?!ACTIVITY).*[\r\n])*ACTIVITY_(?!\1)
```

where the extra stuff in the middle blocks skipping unmatched ACTIVITYs (of course, that won't work either if (1) above is a problem, which may depend on your regexp library).

Comment: I'm using RegEx Coach, as it seems to duplicate the behavior of the application this statement is embedded in ("Tealeaf" privacy rule). I'm only concerned with a match/not match...the number is not important and I'm not using the matched data. It's a trigger for an event.  The trouble I've run into, is that look-aheads seemed to allow the entire expression to still match when it should not...it just suppressed this part of the match from the result. I must have been misusing it.  Both of your examples work, the second looks better. I  could swear I'd tried the first!
Many Thanks!

Comment: no problem (if you mark this answer as correct - by clicking the tick mark below the voting buttons - then i get points :o) (and people are more likely to answer your questions in future)